# How to introduce Swipeable Tabs in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, tabs, android-tabs

I'm following "The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" text book for learning Android App Development. (BTW what a wonderful book! :)) I'm enjoying my learning process. I have limited Java knowledge, so it's taking some time.

**My current situation is:**

I was interested to introduce Swipeable Tab views, but the the text book hasn't covered that portion(Swipeable is covered, but not tab views).

In the Chapter 9 of that book, he explains how it is useful to have an Abstract Super Class, basically **An Abstract Activity for Hosting a single fragment**, to reuse hosting views.

So, in my app development, I have an abstract class called:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container_layout);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
      }
   }
}
```

From this abstract class I'm extending my main activity, in which I'm launching a fragment called TheZooList:

```
public class MainActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {

    return new TheZooList();}
}
```

TheZooList extends a fragment and right now, using an `ArrayAdapter` it is displaying a long list of animals and birds.

```
public class TheZooList extends Fragment
{...}
```

I wish to have two separate lists, one for animals and one for plants, each in a Tab of there own.

I'm basically stuck here. From a popular [blog](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) I'm able to understand how the tabs in android can be introduced, but I'm not able to relate and implement it in my project.

For example, in that they use `implements ActionBar.TabListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {,,,}
```

In my project for which class should I do `implements ActionBar.TabListener`: the `MainActivity` or the `TheZooList` fragment?

Any guidance for next steps will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial covering this topic. Check out this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

In brief: you should use a combination of a ViewPager, and the standard ActionBar tabs. You need to make sure they get notified when the tabs get change using either way of navigation. The implementation is discussed in details in the provided link.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may attract opinions. So here is my advice. `TheZooList` class represents a fragment, that means a fragment can contain only 1 tab (again that is an opinion). However sample projects including Google's uses a tab containing only one fragment, it does not follow the book's sample code. Therefore ActionBar.TabListener makes sense in the MainActivity. Is that clear?  MainActivity may create several tabs, one tab per fragment. To do this, you will have to separate code in a logical manner.

Another, I am not understanding the benefit of `SingleFragmentActivity` class. It does not seem to offer additional benefit compared to `FragmentActivity`, for example. It seems good for explaining Android framework to readers but what do you do with it? The book forces you to be creative.

It seems the book is showing you a lot of code without functionality. Start with Google sample project like [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). I have implemented it. It works but customizing it may be bit difficult. But nothing is too easy with Android GUI framework.

Good luck and have fun...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you use Googles new design library which makes implementing tabs super easy. To include it to your project you just have the latest Android Support Library downloaded in your SDK manager and add this line to the dependencies in your build.gradle file `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

From there you can add a tab bar to your layout easily by using the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` widget and then play with its attributes to get it looking/working how you want.

Follow step 3 from your tutorial and add a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` below your TabLayout.

Follow step 5 and create your own adapter that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`. In your case you will have 2 fragments, your animal fragment and your plant fragment.

Once you've done all that, linking the ViewPager to the TabLayout is as easy as this:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

You just have to get the ViewPager, set its adapter to the one you created earlier. Then to link them together call `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` and you should be all set.

This tutorial may go into more depth what I am trying to explain if you need any more information. http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/

If you need me to elaborate on anything, I'd be happy to.